# How to enlarge font size in TextBox with ctrl + scrollwheel

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some `RichTextBox`:

```
 <RichTextBox x:Name="logTextBox" MouseWheel="LogTextBox_MouseWheel" ... >
```

And I want to increase font's size by using ctrl+mousewheel. I almost got it:

```
    private void LogTextBox_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        if(Keyboard.Modifiers != ModifierKeys.Control)
        {
            return;
        }
        if(e.Delta > 0)
        {
            ++logTextBox.FontSize;
        }
        else
        {
            --logTextBox.FontSize;
        }
    }
```

But there is one problem. In order for this to work I need to scroll up/down to textbox's vertical begin/end. But I'd like it to work properly everywhere, inside a whole textbox. How to fix this?

Comment: What happens if you put the event on the form instead of just the textbox?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use PreviewMouseWheel instead, and make sure you set the Handled flag:

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="logTextBox" PreviewMouseWheel="LogTextBox_PreviewMouseWheel" />


private void LogTextBox_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.Modifiers != ModifierKeys.Control)
    {
        return;
    }

    e.Handled = true;
    if (e.Delta > 0)
    {
        ++logTextBox.FontSize;
    }
    else
    {
        --logTextBox.FontSize;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working well for VB.NET:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_MouseWheel(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.MouseWheel 

    If My.Computer.Keyboard.CtrlKeyDown = True Then
        If e.Delta > 0 Then
            If TrackBar1.Value = 100 Then

            Else
                TrackBar1.Value += 1
                Label1.Font = New Font(Label1.Font.FontFamily, TrackBar1.Value)
                TextBox1.Font = Label1.Font
            End If
        Else
            If TrackBar1.Value = 1 Then

            Else
                TrackBar1.Value -= 1
                Label1.Font = New Font(Label1.Font.FontFamily, TrackBar1.Value)
                TextBox1.Font = Label1.Font
            End If
        End If
        Return
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: In the future, if the question specifies a language, please respond using that language. Obviously this is all .NET, so it should translate pretty easily. But if a reader is struggling with the .NET API, then swapping out the language might just add confusion.